# Excel 2013: Column total using respective last row entry for null cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I calculate a column total including the last row entry for any null cell? With the below table example, the formula should recognize the null r2c3 cell and utilize the r2c2 value of '2' for a total of 11.

[image]

Comment: What if r2c1 in column c1 is null? What value should it consider then?

Comment: I have historical data where all cells in the 1st column have a value. Should have added that point.... thanks

Comment: Is there only ever 1 missing cell per column? If so, simply minus the total from the sum of R1:R4

Comment: there could be zero to multiple empty cells

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To account for the possibility that there can be multiple blanks in a column.

This requires some juggling because MATCH() can't use "" as the lookup value.

But this formula in C6, filled to the right, will do what you ask:

```
  =SUMPRODUCT((C2:C5="")*(B2:B5)+(C2:C5))
```

Because Column B will never have a blank, B6 contains just `=SUM(B2:B5)`

[image]

How it works: Let's consider the formula in D6: (D2:D5="") is a True/False array with True in the position of *all* blanks in the column. Multiplying by C2:C5 converts the True/False values to 1's and 0's and multiplies, returning the array {0;2;0;0}.

Then adding the D2:D5 array back to this gives the array {3;2;3;3}.  And then SUMPRODUCT() totals the array.

Note: This formula won't give the correct answer if there are two successive blanks in the same **row**.

Hope this helps and good luck.